# Running .bat file show Error findstr not recognized from QProcess Qt

Tags: qt, qprocess

I am trying to execute a *.bat file from QProcess with some argument.

While running from Command line it show the log as desired but running from 
QProcess after running the *.bat file it show :

'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

But the findstr.exe is there in C:/Windows/System32 which is included in PATH variable.
I dont know why it is coming while executing from QProcess.
Please let me know if any one having any hint.

command line output : 
 [image: CMD OUTPUT:]

GUI output :

[image: GUI OUTPUT:]

Thanks

Praveen

Comment: Have you tried verifying if PATH has the expected value from within the batch file?

Comment: If I go to :   cd/directory/where/batfileis>build.bat 2 name ;where "2" "name" are 2 argument . Executing from build.bat from its directory gives required output that is Error so there is no problem of PATH when I run from build.bat directory but                                                              In Qt GUI I have set the working directory from Qprocess and then running *.bat file but In last it show findstr not recognized.

Comment: If you run this manually, then it has the environment of the shell. What I meant was check the value of PATH in the script when being run by your program.